# A function on [0,1] that satisfies the following conditions

Tags: calculus, analysis

I am struggling to come up with a function $F(x)$ with $x \in [0,1]$ that satisfy the following conditions (some sort of variants of Inada conditions)

- continuously differentiable
- strictly increasing
- convex
- $F(0) = 0$
- the first order derivative approaches $0$ when $x \rightarrow 0$
- the first order derivative approaches $+\infty$ when $x \rightarrow 1$

Any thought will be appreciated. Thanks for your help in advance!

**Addition:** Also, would it be possible to parameterize this function, say with a parameter $a$, so that $\partial F(x)/\partial x$ is monotonic in $a$?

**Edits:** As correctly pointed out, indeed, what I meant is $F(x)$ continuous on $[0,1]$ and $F'(x)$ continous on $(0,1)$.

Thank you all for the wonderful help!

Comment: It can't satisfy the first and sixth properties.

Comment: @zhw.: I also noticed this (see comments to Hagen von Eitzen's answer). I think OP probably wants continuous derivative on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @zhw Singh Thanks for pointing it out. Indeed, I meant continuous $F'(x)$ on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 13):

What about this (circle arc): $$F(x)=1-\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Comment: Thanks! This is beautiful. Actually, I also need to parameterize the function, say with a parameter $a$, so that $\partial F(x)/\partial a$ is monotonic in $a$. It seems a bit difficult to do so with the circle arc?

Comment: @Hyperplane What about $F(x) = \left( 1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}\right)^a$ for $a \geq 1$?

Comment: Probably something like a "$p$-circle arc" for $p\geq 2$ would work too - $1-(1-x^p)^{1/p}$.

Comment: How is this continuously differentiable on $x \in [0,1]$?

Comment: This works if the domain is $(0, 1)$, but not if it's $[0, 1]$

Comment: @Mehrdad: if it's continuously differentiable on $[0,1]$ then by being continuous the derivative is bounded and hence can't tend to $\infty$ as $x\to 1^{-}$. So I think the question needs to be more like $f $ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $f'$ is continuous on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Ah... my mistake was for some reason I read the question as "*Is* there a function..." and was confused why the answer wasn't a simple "no". Yeah, you're probably right.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for pointing it out. Indeed, I meant $F'(x)$ continuous on $(0,1)$. Have edited the question too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest would be $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x^2}-1$